# Which is correct: I've (just) cancelled the trained/train armies?

Tags: word-choice, past-participles, compounds

Which of these phrases is correct:

> I've just cancelled the trained armies?

Or

> I've cancelled the train armies?

I've just played *[Clash of Clans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clash_of_Clans#Clans_and_clan_wars)* and one of my friends says he *has cancelled the train or trained armies.*

He had done his training armies but he just dumb them that's why he told me he had cancelled the "trained or train armies" These two words I'm confused whether the correct one is **trained** or **train**.

Comment: I'm just curious whether that sentence is correct or not. And just point out the mistakes

Comment: The correct word is either trained or train in that sentence

Answer (score 1):

I would say

> I've just cancelled the **army training**

The expression, **trained armies**, means armies that have been trained for combat, to cancel *them*, as the OP's friend seems to have said, would suggest that the player has ***deleted*** them. *Train armies*, makes sense only if it is part of a clause, as in:

1. We need to **train** the **army**
2. You can **train** the **army** faster if...
3. In order to **train** the **army**, you need...
4. **Train armies**, build fortresses...
   etc.

For the actual grammar, see @Jason Bassford's answer

Answer (score 0):

Both versions of the sentence are fine.

You use *just* if you want to emphasize that something happened in the very recent passed as opposed to at some unspecified past time.

From Merriam-Webster's [definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/just#h2) of the adverb:

> **1 b** : very recently
>   // the bell *just* rang

In the right context, there is no reason to use *just*, as it will be assumed. If it was raining a minute ago, and has since stopped, anybody who knows it *was* raining a minute ago won't need to hear *just* to know that it's stopped in the past minute.

But even if the time frame is understood, and there is no need to use *just*, using it causes no problems. Some people will say it anyway.

If it's *not* known how long ago something happened, then using *just* makes it more obvious that it was recent.

Comment: Thanks mate but trying to improve my grammars especially how to frame past sentences

Comment: @PhrangkuparNongbet You used *just* in one sentence, but not the other. I addressed that difference. Are you saying that you aren't interested in that difference?

Comment: Of course I do sir

Comment: Please show me the difference

Comment: @PhrangkuparNongbet I don't understand. I *did* explain the difference that *just* makes to the sentence.